# Please Identify Painting Signature

Tags: translation

I have bought these painting years ago but now I am doing some research to find out who is the artist and what is written in chinese calligraphy.

[image: Chinese Painting]

Kindly help me with.

Thanks
Sachin

Answer (score 0):

The signature looks like 笑宜. And the year 庚申 may refer to 1920 or 1980 depending on the age of the painting.

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding and identifying the character. I want to know what is the English translation for artist name and what are those poem in English.

Comment: @Sachin there is no translation for a Name and that's not poem. It just says the when and where and who painted what.

Comment: @Sachin it's not a poem. It means March of the year of 庚申. The place is 延陵[yán líng] which is in Jiangsu Province.  The artist's name is Xiao Yi.